# GD @imagecreatefromjpeg dies on an image

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to create an image from a jpeg file (but it has some Adobe RGB, Gimp warning when opening a copy of it for conversion).

The original file is at `http://learnintouch.com/Bernadotte.jpg`

My source code:

The die statement will NOT display.

```
try {
  $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
  die("$file");
} catch (Exception $e) {
  reportError("Could not use imagecreatefromjpeg() to create an image from the $file file.");
  exit();
}
```

Or:

Only the print A displays.

```
      try {
print("A");
        $copy = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
print("B");
      } catch (Exception $e) {
print("C");
        reportError("Could not use imagecreatefrompng() to create an image from the $filename file. " . $e->getMessage());
        exit();
      }
```

The catch will NOT run.

The execution dies inside the imagecreatefromjpeg method.

I'm using PHP 5.6.16 and GD is:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.9
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 8
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.49
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
@imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
```

The `@` is an 'Error Control Operator' meant to [suppress any errors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). From the documentation:

> Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable
>   error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script
>   execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to
>   suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available
>   or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no
>   indication as to why.

My suspicion is that an exception is being raised, but because the `@` has set the error level to 0, your `reportError` function is not operating as you expect. (I can't confirm this without seeing that function, and perhaps knowing a bit more about your logging situation.) Regardless, you should remove the `@` if you intend to handle errors in a `try/catch`: the only time that operator is appropriate is if you need to suppress errors while bringing up the framework or code that would handle errors.

Comment: Good suspicion, but it's not that. At first my function didn't have te @ operator. It happens the same without it. Also it happens with png and possible others... I updated the question.

Comment: Interesting. Is this running inside another application? For instance, are you seeing apache error logs or other indications of a fatal?

Comment: It is a normal php web application. I must admit I didn't look at the Apache log. It only happened with these 3 images www.europasprak.com/Alger4.png www.europasprak.com/Bernadotte.jpg www.europasprak.com/DSC01720.JPG So I got rid of them and proceeded further.